# Filtering dropdown form with jquery.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two dropdown getting value from database:

**Table_Buildings**

> |id|---|building_name|

**Table_Floors**

> |id|---|Floor_name|---|building(Foreign key to table_Buildings)|

and in my form

Dropdown: building)

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT buildings.building_name, floors.id 
               FROM buildings 
               INNER JOIN floors 
               ON buildings.id=floors.id"
```

Dropdown: floor)

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT floor_name, id FROM floors");
```

For filtering my dropdown I want to use this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xhr;
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#filter_building').change(function(){
        var filterBuilding = $('#filter_building').val(); 
        if (xhr && xhr.abort) {
            xhr.abort();xhr=false;
            }
        xhr = jQuery.ajax( {
            url: 'index.php', 
            data: 'option=com_mycomponent', 
            success: function(data){
                jQuery('#filter_building').replaceWith(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But somewhere is wrong and its not working.

Comment: what was the error you got?

Comment: there is no error, my second dropdown is loading all options without depending on first dropdown.

Comment: did you pass the building value to function and use it in query with WHERE condition?  I think you doen't.

Comment: can you explain more plz

Comment: You pass the value of $('#filter_building').val(); to index.php and get it there by use $_GET['filter_building']. Use that it to query $db->setQuery("SELECT floor_name, id FROM floors WHERE filter_building=$_GET['filter_building']");. Did try this one?

Comment: getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: let me explain more,in joomla i created component and in the backend i can filter in my list views, for frontend i created form with RSform so the dropdown populating from database and im trying to filter the second dropdown with ajax.

Comment: Changes in query format use this $db->setQuery("SELECT floor_name, id FROM floors WHERE filter_building='".$_GET['filter_building']."'");

Comment: now the second dropdown is not show anything

Comment: can you show the index.php?

Comment: [link](http://blackdeers.net/project/pcp/contact) im on this page

Comment: ok i have seen it. and i have given sample code for your problem. Please change query column name according to yours.

Comment: Thanks, i saw your sample, i made comments and post my codes can you check them?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#filter_building').change(function(){

    var buildingId = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {buildingId: buildingId}, 
        success: function(data) {
            $('select#floor-id').html(data); 
           // data = '<option>val1</option><option>val2</option>'
        }
    });
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sample jquery and function in index.php
Jquery and ajax

```
$('#filter_building').change(function(){
var buildingId =  $('#filter_building').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {buildingId: buildingId}, 
    success: function(data) {
        if(data != "false")
    {
        $('#Floor').html(data); 
    }
    else{
    alert("No value");}
    }
});
});
```

And In index.php page

```
$buildingId = JRequest::getVar('buildingId');
$db->setQuery("SELECT floor_name, id FROM floors WHERE filter_building='".$_GET['filter_building']."'");
$db->query();
$num_rows = $db->getNumRows();
if($num_rows>0){
while($nt = $db->loadAssoc()){
echo "<option value=$nt['id']>$nt['floor_name']</option>"; 
}
}
else
{
echo "false";
}
```

Comment: here is my code for first dropdowns: $items = array();

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$items[] = "|Please Select[c]";
 

$db->setQuery("SELECT #__pk_buildings.building_name, #__pk_floors.id FROM #__pk_buildings INNER JOIN #__pk_floors ON #__pk_buildings.id=#__pk_floors.id");
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($results as $result) {
  $value = $result->id;
  $label = $result->building_name;
  $items[] = $value.'|'.$label;
}
 

$items = implode("\n", $items);
 

return $items;

Comment: and second dropdown is:  $items = array();

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$items[] = "|Please Select[c]";
 

$db->setQuery("SELECT floor_name, id FROM #__pk_floors WHERE building='".$_GET['filter_building']."'");
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
 

foreach ($results as $result) {
  $value = $result->id;
  $label = $result->floor_name;
  $items[] = $value.'|'.$label;
}
 

$items = implode("\n", $items);
 

return $items;

Comment: an ajax : <script type="text/javascript">
var xhr;
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#building').change(function(){
        var filterBuilding = $('#building').val(); 
        if (xhr && xhr.abort) {
            xhr.abort();xhr=false;
            }
        xhr = jQuery.ajax( {
            url: 'index.php', 
            data: 'option=com_pk', 
            success: function(data){
                jQuery('#building').replaceWith(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

Comment: ok be sure query result is print for second drop down box. and try this code to replace?

Comment: in ajax code , data:'option=com_pk' is correct or i have to get task and filter?

Comment: I think now you got the results. just need little modification in your code.

Comment: See you the problem in returning the result. Something missed like ' quotation. Checked it

Comment: i updated my ajax code with this data: 'option=com_pk&task=floors&format=raw' but still is not working.

Comment: Hey in index.php which print the second drop down box elements,  there is a bug. Because u got some drop down menus in second one. But not exact results.

Comment: can u check it again there was another test form on index.php which i replaced with which we are talking about here

Answer (score 0):

```
<strong>
    <div class="float-right">
        <span>From: </span><input type="date" name="From1" id="From1" />
        <span>To: </span><input type="date" name="To1" id="To1" />
        <input type="submit" value="Get Details" onclick="GetDetailsFromToTransactions()" />
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="smallsize1 float-right" id="filterdropdown">
        <select id="selectBox" onchange="FilterDate(value);">
            <option value="0" Idselected>Select Filter</option>
            <option value="1">Today</option>
            <option value="-1">Last 1 Month</option>
            <option value="-3">Last 3 Months</option>
            <option value="-6">Last 6 Months</option>
            <option value="-9">Last 9 Months</option>
            <option value="-12">Last 1 Year</option>
            <option value="-24">Last 2 Years</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</strong>
```